# JavaScript Display Loader while Controller Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I have a JQuery Function that is calling a controller when 
Controller Response (success()) it is loading an iFrame; 
Basically; converter is returning success function after 30 seconds, for that reason I am trying to display a loading image using

```
beforeSend: function()
{
},
```

Function I tried a lots but its not working; Could you please give me advice how can I achieve it. My code are given bellow:

```
    var callController = function (FirstName, documentId, fileName, packet) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:63902/Home/Preview?DocumentId=" + documentId + "&FileName=" + fileName + "&packet=" + packet,
        cache: false,
        async: false,

        //controller happens...

        success: function (returnedValue) {
            rememberDocumentId(documentId);
            location.reload("#mainIframe");
            setTimeout(function () {

            }, 3000);

            document.getElementById("mainIframe").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("documentIframe").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("documentIframe").src = "http://localhost:63902/FileProcessing/PDFProcessing/TempPDF/" + returnedValue;

            event.preventDefault();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        }
    });

};
```

Comment: var callController = function (FirstName, documentId, fileName, SL) { //You can show loader here

Comment: Hi 
I am trying to  call Loader.html  <br/>
document.getElementById("mainIframe").src = "http://localhost:63902/Loading.html but not working

Comment: what is the issues you can do it here?

Comment: This is the code I tried 
function BeforeSend:function() {
    location.reload("#mainIframe");
    document.getElementById("mainIframe").src = "http://localhost:63902/Loading.html"
}

Comment: you can follow the Junius Rendel answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can show your loader right after or before `$.ajax({...})` but you should **never use `async:false`**, this is the **root of evil**, it will freeze the browser while the request has not succeeded.

like this:

```
var callController = function (FirstName, documentId, fileName, SL) {
//here
showLoader();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:63902/Home/Preview?DocumentId=" + documentId + "&FileName=" + fileName + "&SL=" + SL,
    cache: false,

    //controller happens...

    success: function (returnedValue) {
        rememberDocumentId(documentId);
        location.reload("#mainIframe");
        setTimeout(function () {

        }, 3000);

        document.getElementById("mainIframe").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("documentIframe").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("documentIframe").src = "http://localhost:63902/FileProcessing/PDFProcessing/TempPDF/" + returnedValue;
       //hide Here
        hideLoader();
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        //hide Here
        hideLoader();
    }
});
}
```

Comment: I tried Junius Rendel's solution but having following error :

Unhandled exception at line 62, column 12135 in http://localhost:49664/fa4753a5553f47a5964e056d13af0c39/browserLink

0x8000ffff - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid calling object

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
 
And my showLoader() is as follows: 
var ShowLoader = function() {
     location.reload("#documentIframe");
    //alert("I am inside Loader");
    document.getElementById("documentIframe").src = "http://localhost:63902/Loading.html";
}

Comment: I am feeling problem in #mainIframe and #documentIframe 
var ShowLoader = function() {
    location.reload("#mainIframe");
    document.getElementById("documentIframe").src = "http://localhost:63902/Loading.html";
}

Comment: This project is bit painful; Main page will load only once and after that different location would be change based click events; I found iFrame is the easy solution to bring all others aspx pages inside page using iframe.

Comment: ah yeah, ASP, such sh***y errors are Microsoft tailored:
"0x8000ffff - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid calling object" :D

Comment: can you try in another browser, I'd prefer hang myself than trying to understand IE error descriptions?

Comment: I tried in Chrome but having error; 
However, I have to develop IE8 compatible

Comment: I'd like chrome's output